# ¿Cómo paso el siguiente fragmento de código que select a checked?

Tags: html, angular

Necesito pasar el siguiente select a checked

```
<select class="form-control d-none" formControlName="manageable_communities" multiple>
<option *ngFor="let com of communities" value={{com.id}}>
    {{com.name}}</option>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<mat-select [formControl]="manageable_communities" multiple> 
               <mat-option *ngFor="let com of communities" [value]="com.id" 
                             ">
                        {{ com.name}} 
                </mat-option> 
 </mat-select>
```

https://stackblitz.com/angular/kkrlkqomggj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fselect-multiple-example.ts

Comment: Por favor lee [answer], editar y explicar como tu código resuelve el problema del OP enriquecería mucho tu aporte